# How to retrieve the flashed binary in ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, micropython, flashing

I was able to flash a micropython binary which I'd cross compiled some 6 months ago, and it was working fine. It was built from master branch at that point of time, and I did not save the code, nor the binary.

Today, when I again compiled, the binary is having problem at a point. So I want to revert back to the old binary, only problem is I'm not sure what commitID/build the master was at at that point of time ~6 months ago when my compiled binary which works fine was created.

I do have an ESP which has that binary flashed into it. So I was thinking if there is a way to retrieve the binary from the ESP?

Please let me know if this can be done somehow via ampy, etc..
Or suggest me some workaround. I'm already trying to find out the approximate commit around that time, and would cross compile again, which I'm not sure if would work as expected.

Comment: Anything else needed here?

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of *which* firmware you loaded onto your ESP8266 module (NodeMCU, MicroPython, Arduino, etc.) you can use [`esptool.py`](https://github.com/espressif/esptool#read-flash-contents-read_flash) to dump the flash content to a file like so:

```
./esptool.py -p PORT -b 460800 read_flash 0 0x200000 flash_contents.bin
```

`read_flash` is the command, `0x200000` the argument for the upper memory bound (2MB).

Comment: I'll try this and then upvote if it works. Thanks a ton @marcel

Comment: I used `esptool.py read_flash 0 0x100000 flash_contents.bin` to read 1MB of flash but it is throwing an error `A fatal error occurred: Corrupt data, expected 0x1000 bytes but received 0xffd bytes` what should I do? my flash is 1MB

Comment: "what should I do" - post it as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

For reading the firmware as a BIN file
For reading the firmware as a BIN file you need FIRST to connect correct the FTDI with the pins on the IR module

FTDI to IR Module as follows

```
FTDI 3.3 V    to  IR 3.3 V,
FTDI GND      to  IR GND,
FTDI GND      to  IR IO0 (flash mode - IMPORTANT otherwise it will not work),
FTDI RX       to  IR TXD,
FTDI TX       to  IR RXD
```

Then run the command (if the COM port is 5 and the name to extract the bin is flash-contents, otherwise you replace them to match your COM and the name you wish to have) – important the baud rate to be 9600

```
esptool.py -p COM5 -b 9600 read_flash 0 0x200000 flash_contents.bin
```

Below is the outcome for me (running under python 3.10.2 on windows 11):

```
  PS F:\> esptool.py -p COM5 -b 9600 read_flash 0 0x200000 flash_contents.bin
  esptool.py v3.2
  Serial port COM5
  Connecting....
  Detecting chip type... Unsupported detection protocol, switching and trying 
  again...
  Connecting...
  Detecting chip type... ESP8266
  Chip is ESP8266EX
  Features: WiFi
  Crystal is 26MHz
  MAC: 10:52:1c:f8:b7:c7
  Stub is already running. No upload is necessary.
 2097152 (100 %)
 2097152 (100 %)
 Read 2097152 bytes at 0x0 in 2215.2 seconds (7.6 kbit/s)...
 Hard resetting via RTS pin...
 PS F:\>
```

Remember the `esptool.py -p COM5 -b 9600 read_flash 0 0x200000 flash_contents.bin` is for 2MB memory

but it is well run with `esptool.py -p COM5 -b 9600 read_flash 0 0x100000 flash_contents.bin` for 1MB memory as it was in my IR Module

Answer (score 0):

I reduced the speed of reading the flash memory of my esp8266
460800 for "46080" I took a zero.
and successful

My system is a windows 10

```
C:\Users\POSITIVO\Downloads\esptool-master\esptool-master>esptool.py -p COM6 -b 46080 read_flash 0 0x400000 flash_contents3.bin
esptool.py v3.0-dev
Serial port COM6
Connecting....
Detecting chip type... ESP8266
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
Crystal is 26MHz
MAC: 2c:3a:e8:42:b9:f7
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
4194304 (100 %)
4194304 (100 %)
Read 4194304 bytes at 0x0 in 937.7 seconds (35.8 kbit/s)...
Hard resetting via RTS pin...
```

Answer (score 0):

hi guys one surprise today... i just opened one esp8266 esp 12e and Read flash in programer.. 16mb.... after i try to read by phyton esp tool... 16 mb to... not 4mb how is putting in datasheet.... so for full backup.... programer only.... there will be a lot of sensitivo info too... ssid... wifi paswords... accounts paswords entere too.. so for full backup hardware only..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).